# When algebraic topology fails

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Various techniques from point-set topology enable us to determine whether 2 topological spaces are homeomorphic or not. If one is Hausdorff/compact/connected/metrizable while the other is not, then they are not homeomorphic. But this does not carry us very far: it is difficult to distinguish the sphere from the torus. People therefore invented algebraic topology, including the homotopy, homology and cohomology theory. But are there places where even these tools fail? Say, do you have examples of topological spaces in which they share all the same common point sets topological properties, and homotopy types?

Comment: If Murphy's law is to be believed, when you need it the most.

Comment: The first example that comes to mind (and may fit) is that the tools you listed have problems distinguishing a trefoil knot from its mirror image. That is hardly a surprise given that taking the mirror image is obviously a homeomorphism. But, I'm not an expert on either algebraic topology or the theory of knots, so I am prepared to be wrong about this.

Comment: How about homotopy equivalent, but not homeomorphic, manifolds of the same dimension? The lens spaces $L(7,1)$ and $L(7,2)$ satisfy this, for instance.

Comment: Can algebraic topology decide whether or not every simply connected closed $3$-manifold is homeomorphic to the $3$-sphere ?

Comment: @MikeMiller The proof that such things are not homeomorphic usually invokes something like Whitehead torsion to show no simple homotopy equivalence exists. This seems completely rooted in algebraic topology to me. This may answer the last question of the OP but it sure seems like it is not a case of a failure of algebraic topology to distinguish two spaces.

Comment: There are two types of problems to consider here. Showing existence of an isomorphism between two objects and obstructing the existence of such an isomorphism. These sets of problems are usually done using starkly distinct methods and algebraic topology is mostly about dealing with the second. For instance answering a question like Poincare in the positive probably can't be done with any theory using only tools suited to answering  the second type of question.

Comment: @PVAL-inactive: I'd agree that the latter question is more one of geometric rather than algebraic topology. The example I have in the back of my head is the proof of Poincare in high dimensions: take a sphere-like space (in whatever category: C^0, PL, smooth), chop off small caps around the putative north and south poles, use the h-cobordism theorem to show that the remainder is just a cylinder, and then reattach the caps.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Here's a short treatment, for example: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/torsion.pdf . The result of Reidemeister about classifying lens spaces you mentioned in Theorem 8. (I think it's also mentioned, though obviously not proved, in Hatcher. I vaguely recall it being in one of his other books or proto-books besides the big algebraic topology one, but I might be misremembering.)